# Angular: How To Introduce External Domain Objects Into A Controller?

Tags: angularjs

My application has a number of domain model objects that I've already built and unit tested.  There is nothing angular-specific about them, they have no angular dependencies, and I could just as well use them if I had selected some other framework besides angular.

My question is about the proper way to use them within angular.  I need to use them in a controller.  Currently I'm just including them before my angular controller code, so they are already defined and I can simply refer to them. But I'd like to know if there is a better way?  Should I be using angular's dependency injection system to inject them?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just stick them in a service.  Then they can be injected / mocked / tested / DI-is-fun-ed easily.

Before:

```
var SuperBigThing = {
  isAwesome: true;
};
```

After:

```
myApp.factory('SuperBigThing', function() {
  var SuperBigThing = {
    isAwesome: true
  };
  return SuperBigThing;
});

myApp.controller('ThingCtrl', function($scope, SuperBigThing) {
});
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the reply.  I was wondering about this exactly.  I was under the impression that services were for items that were more application wide and re-used in multiple places.  Is it still considered good practice to create one for objects that will likely appear in only a single controller?